# Como puedo acceder a la propiedad de un objeto [[{"userRealName":"Antonio"}]] Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, objeto, jsonobject, mssql

mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo acceder a la propiedad de un objeto que me devuelve mi endpoint?

Estoy usando el paquete **rest-mssql-nodejs**

[[{"userRealName":"Antonio"}]]

en mi localhost si llego a la propiedad usando  `query.data[0][0].userRealName`

```
const restsql = new  (require('rest-mssql-nodejs'))({
    user:'tester',
    password:'****',
    server: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'ide',
    enableArithAbort: true

});

 api.post('/inicio', async (req, res) => {

        let result = await petition(req)

        if(res.status(200)){
            res.status(200).send("Estatus del servidor 2000 y la consulta es "  + result);
            //console.log("parametro usuario " + req.body.usuario)
            //res.send("Se han recibido los datos, estatus " + res.status);
        }        
    });
    

const petition = async (req) =>{
        const query = await restsql.executeQuery('select userRealName from users where userName = @usuario and userPass = @pass',[{
            name:'usuario',
            type:'varchar',
            value: req.body.usuario 
        },{
            name:'pass',
            type:'varchar',
            value: req.body.pass
        }])
        
        console.log( query.data.length)
        console.log(query.data[0][0].userRealName)
        return query.data[0][0].userRealName
    }
```

pero en un servidor de pruebas, no me deja acceder a la propiedad de la misma manera  ( `query.data[0][0].userRealName`
)

Me devuelve un error diciendo

*Fri, 19 Nov 2021 16:36:34 GMT tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. at node_modules\rest-mssql-nodejs\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23
(node:22708) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')** *